# dotnet ef migrations issue in Ubuntu 19.10. Dotnet sdk 3.1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dotnetcorecli

I installed `dotnet ef` tool in order to generate migrations for a dotnet core project am working on using the command. `dotnet tool install -g dotnet-ef`. The installation was successfull. In order to us `dotnet ef` i have installed the nuget packages below

1. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
2. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
3. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore
4. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

When trying to generate migrations using the command `dotnet ef migrations add IdentityandCategory` i get the output below.

```
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '3.1.1' was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      2.1.14 at [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      2.2.8 at [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      3.1.0 at [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.

The specified framework can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=3.1.1&arch=x64&rid=ubuntu.19.10-x64
```

I reinstall dotnet 3.1.1 but this trouble continues. `dotnet info` seem to detect the version
when i run `donet --info`

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.1.100
 Commit:    cd82f021f4

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  19.10
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.19.10-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.100/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.1.0
  Commit:  157910edee

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.802 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
  2.2.402 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
  3.1.100 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.14 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.8 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.14 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.8 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.0 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.14 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.8 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.0 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

How can i solve this issues?  Thank in advance for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this issue today on Azure Pipelines. The easiest way to fix it is to explicitly install `dotnet-ef` by specifying the exact version you need.

`dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 3.1.0`

I believe that the .NET Core Runtime version and the `dotnet-ef` version have to be in sync. Since there was a security patch released recently that bumped .NET Core Runtime up to `3.1.1`, there is a mismatch and that is why it is complaining.

That said, it is probably wise to just update everything to `3.1.1` when time permits.